# Scripts inside HTML page via Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this situation:

I pass a variable via url to an HTML page. The page grabs it via javascript and load via ajax a portion of HTML stored in a file. The first html page (the one who read the variable via url) has some scripts in it.

How can i get them working? I tried with:

```
$.get('/it_IT/eni_nel_mondo/'+page, function(data){
    $('body').prepend(data);
});
```

It reads the content and it seems also the scripts, but it doesn't execute them.

I pasted the entire code here: http://jsbin.com/uceper (it doesn't display anything, so get the source)

Answer (score 1):

The script existing in your **HTML fragment** (or HTML portion as you mentioned) won't be executed, maybe because there is no entry point for it. I mean for ajax-loaded scripts, DOMReady won't fire. 
I suggest using **self-invoked functions**.

Update:
this function won't be executed when loaded via ajax:

```
function getTime()
{
 // Getting the time;
}
```

but would be executed this way:

```
(function getTime()
{
 // Getting the time;
})();
```

Comment: actually the scripts are not inside the html fragment but only in the first html page.
i try to explain better the schema:
page 1 -> link with variable in the href (page2.html?page=page3.html)
page 2 -> load via ajax the page3.html and has scripts in it.

the ajax call works fine: i get the page3.html but the scripts has no effect on this portion of html

Comment: It makes no difference. What you get from server is of `Internet Media Type text/html`, and browser deals with it as HTML.

Comment: i didn't get the point:
i get it as html and it's ok. the problem is not in the ajax call but it's on the scripts not working the content of the html called via ajax

Comment: I meant that browser loads the script. OK, then what? It should execute those scripts. But when? There is no `onload` event here. See the update :)